# Need to display ID in label on selecting value in autocomplete Textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, autocompleteextender

I have the *AutoCompleteExtender* that autocompletes *tbDrugName*. So far, it pulls *DrugIds* from my database.
What I want is for it to autocomplete *DrugNames* and on selection, display *DrugId* in a *lbllist* label next to it.

[image]

This is my cs code:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethodAttribute(), System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethodAttribute()]
public static List<string> GetDrugNames(string prefixText, int count, string contextKey)
{

    SqlConnection sc1 = new SqlConnection();
    sc1.ConnectionString = "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=Drug;Integrated Security=True";
    sc1.Open();
    /*Opens connection to drugTable and does string matching*/
    SqlCommand getdrugnames = new SqlCommand("Select * from DrugTable where DrugID like @Name+'%'", sc1);
    getdrugnames.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", prefixText);
    List<string> DrugNames = new List<string>();
    using (SqlDataReader sdr = getdrugnames.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (sdr.Read())
        {
            string item = AjaxControlToolkit.AutoCompleteExtender.CreateAutoCompleteItem(sdr["DrugID"].ToString(), sdr["DrugName"].ToString());
            //item.drugid, item.drugname
            DrugNames.Add(item);
            //DrugNames has list objects
        }
    }   

    return DrugNames;
}
```

This is my aspx code:

```
<ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
</ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>
<asp:TextBox ID="tbDrugName" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
<ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender 
            ID="AutoCompleteDrugID" runat="server" 
            TargetControlID="tbDrugName" 
            ServiceMethod="GetDrugNames"
            MinimumPrefixLength="1" 
            CompletionInterval="200" 
            UseContextKey="True"  
            >

    </ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender>    
</ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender>

<asp:Label ID="lbllist" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use javascript in order to achieve that, add the "onChange" attribute to the text box and when the text box value changes then directly change the label text.

Put this in Page_Load event in code behind:

```
this.tbDrugName.Attributes.Add("OnChange", "tbDrugName_OnChange()");
```

And add this javascript function in markup:

```
        function tbDrugName_OnChange() {
            var txtVal = document.getElementById('<%= tbDrugName.ClientID %>').value;
            document.getElementById('<%= lblList.ClientID %>').innerText = txtVal;
        }
```

Comment: this worked perfectly with me, sure you're missing something can you make sure of that you used a valid controls names in javascript function? if it still doesn't work please modify your question with the edited code so that I can detect the problem.

Comment: Thanks. I scrapped autocomplete and I'm using dropdown lists instead.